# How to use Linux "cut" in parallel

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, gnu, cut, gnu-parallel

I have a large tab delimited file (10TB).

I would like to cut the file by certain columns, and I would like to do it in parallel, using each of my 24 cores.

```
cut -f1,2,3 file > out
```

Any thoughts on how to do this using multiple cores, or in parallel ..?

I have some ideas like

```
cat file | parallel --round-robin --pipe  "cut -f1 1,2,3"  > out

cat file | parallel --round-robin --pipe --block 1000000k "cut -f1 1,2,3"  > out
```

Comment: This isn't as useful as you might think. The time consuming thing here is streaming data from disk, not the `cut` operation.

Comment: Sobrique is most lilkely right. `iostat -dkx 1` is good at showing the utilization of disks.

Answer (score 1):

IF disk is not the limiting factor (but CPU is):

```
parallel -k --pipepart -a big.tsv --block 1g cut -f1 1,2,3 > out
```

Comment: Is there a concern here that the rows/blocks may not be in the same order depending on when each thread finishes?  (ie the thread with block2 finishes before the thread with block1)

Comment: `-k` keeps the order. So the order of the output will be the same as running sequentially.